# C# cannot cast from class type to interface type

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to make a picture galerie in the mvvm pattern. The viewmodel should have a model of the type IGalerieModel so that the viewmodels supports different model types in case I want to create a view with other pictures in it.

The viewmodel looks like this:

```
GalerieViewModel<TView, TModel> 
    where: TView is Galerieview
    where: TModel is IGalerieModel
```

To call methods from code behind to the viewmodel I need to cast the datacontext. For that I have a DataContext property. It is of the type:

```
GalerieViewModel<GalerieView, IGalerieModel>();
```

But if I try to cast the DataContext into this type it return null. The datacontext isn't null I checked that, it just can't cast it to the viewModel type. 
Why is this and does anybody have an alternative solution?

Edit:
Some related code, where I try to cast the datacontext.

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedItem = Images.SelectedItem as Image;
    if(selectedItem != null)
    {
         var datacontext = DataContext as GalerieViewModel<GalerieView, IGalerieModel>;
         datacontext?.RemoveImage(selectedItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you do the cast? Can you show us some related code?

Comment: I am pretty sure you are hitting the *can't downcast generic type* problem, The solution is to use interfaces only. I can't find a decent duplicate though.

Comment: Your `ViewModel` should be ignorant of the type of the `View`. So why do you have `TView` in your ViewModel?

Comment: @Dai It makes it easier to link my views. I know its not the proper way. But that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: @HansDabi It is, because if you eliminate `TView` then you don't need `GalarieViewModel<TView,TModel>` at all and can use `TModel` as your DataContext directly, which solves the casting issue you're having.

Comment: @PatrickHofman But how can I use Interfaces only when I can't create an instance of my model and set it to the interface type? It always says it can't be casted.

Comment: @Dai But the datacontext should be of the viewmodel type and not of the model type. If I eliminate the    TView     then I would have the type     GalerieViewModel<TModel>    and it would be the same problem again.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I don't cast it down, I want to cast it from GalerieViewModel<GalerieView, SomeModel> to GalerieViewModel<GalerieView, IGalerieModel> this would be an upcast or am I wrong?

Comment: Besides what was mentioned in the above comments, why would you want to remove an Image control (by RemoveImage) from your GalerieViewModel? Your view model shouldn't know anything of view elements like Image controls. You should rework your view model to be unaware of views and UI elements (and IMO call it "Gallery..." instead of "Galerie...").

Comment: @Clemens It's not an image control it's a class I created. The ViewModel has a list which contains objects of this class. It's nothing more than a wrapper for a string path and some methods to load the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using inheritance in this case.

I'm using the following terminology:

- **ViewModel** an object which is an encapsulation of the data (both bidirectional and unidirectional) displayed and/or consumed by a single specific **View**.

  - For example, if your system has 3 screens/windows (`LoginView`, `OrdersListView`, `OrderDetailView`), each would have its own ViewModel (`LoginVM`, `OrdersListVM`, `OrderDetailVM`).
  - If your application is built around a single large view (and your application does not permit multiple instances of the view) then it is permissable to have a monolithic ViewModel with nested/child ViewModels for any child views (have fun with event binding, though!)
- **Model** a business domain entity, of whose provenance is not the concern of the **ViewModel**. I believe it is valid to expose a domain entity object directly to the **View** for rendering as it helps DRY. In many simplistic and trivial cases you can use the domain entity object as the ViewModel directly, assuming you don't need bi-directional binding and data-transfer. But in many cases it is highly inappropriate.
- **View** the presentation layer of your system, in this context we specifically refer to some specific subclass of `System.Windows.Controls.Window` or `System.Windows.Controls.Control` which acts as a discrete component.

  - As an aside, when MVVM is implemented correctly it is possible to substitute the entire WPF layer for some other presentation/view system or even the entire runtime environment, such as WinForms or UWP (but not ASP.NET MVC as the entire stateful paradigm breaks down).

In your case, I'm assuming `IGalerieModel` is an interface for your *business domain entity* types and it generally wraps/encapsulates bitmap data. I can't think of how the data could be different, but I'll just take your word for it.

So you have a single view, `GalerieView`, which I assume is a simple `*.xaml` view, with a lightweight, view-logic-only `.cs` CodeBehind file.

Your ViewModel should therefore look something like this:

```
public class GalerieViewModel {

    public String WindowTitle { get; set; }
    public String WelcomeMessage { get; set; }
    public virtual ObservableCollection<IGalerieModel> Images { get; set; }
}
```

So there is no need to use generics here at all.

If you do want to use generics because elsewhere in your system there is knowledge about the exact type of object in the `Images` collection, you should implement that functionality in a generic subclass:

```
public class GalerieViewModel<TImage>
    where TImage : IGalerieModel {

    public new ObservableCollection<TImage> Images { get; set; }
}
```

(Note that you will need to write code to keep both `ObservableCollection` collections in-sync, note that `ObservableCollection<IGalerieModel>` is more permissive in what it accepts as input compared to `ObservableCollection<TImage>` - this is a downside of using mutable collections in generics, as well as how `ObservableCollection` works in practice).

Then you can consume it like so (using your example):

```
private void MenuItem_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    IGalerieModel selectedItem = this.Images.SelectedItem as IGalerieModel ;
    if( selectedItem != null )
    {
         GalerieViewModel viewModel = (GalerieViewModel)this.DataContext;
         viewModel.Images.Remove( selectedItem );
    }
}
```

For convenience you can add a strongly-typed property to get the `ViewModel` in the `View` (this is okay because the View knows about the ViewModel, but the ViewModel doesn't know about the View):

```
protected GalerieViewModel ViewModel {
    get { return (GalerieViewModel)this.DataContext; }
}

private void MenuItem_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    IGalerieModel selectedItem = this.Images.SelectedItem as IGalerieModel;
    if( selectedItem != null )
    {
         this.ViewModel.Images.Remove( selectedItem );
    }
}
```

You might want to subclass `Window` to add strongly-typed ViewModel support:

```
public abstract class Window2<TViewModel> : Window {

    protected TViewModelViewModel {
        get { return (TViewModel)this.DataContext; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer, seems like I will have to change my code a bit ;)

Answer (score 0):

`GalerieViewModel<GalerieView, SomeModel>` and `GalerieViewModel<GalerieView, IGalerieModel>` are two completely independent types that cannot be casted.

`SomeModel` implementing `IGalerieModel` does not propagate out of the generic.